# mongodb indexing embedded fields (no dot notation)

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I would like to know if in Mongo it is possible to create an index on embedded fields without using dot notation and how to do it. Our client is asking for this other option but we can't find any reference in the official documentation (unless we are mistaken).

Has anyone done it before? Any advice on this topic?

Thank you very much,
Irene.

Comment: What is the problem with using a dot?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.